# Catching a 500 server error in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I love Flask's error catching.  It's beautifully simple:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def pageNotFound(error):
    return "page not found"
```

works like charm.  But it doesn't work for the 500 error code.  I want to catch Python errors when something goes wrong an exception is raised in the code.  Is that possible?

I should note that if I explicitly call `return abort(500)` in a view then the 500 errorhandler does work.  So this is explicitly for when the Python code fails.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for? I don't understand what you mean by "I want to catch Python errors when something goes wrong an exception is raised in the code". Do you mean that if in a normal view raises a Python exception, you expect the 500 error handler to be called automatically?

Comment: That's correct, if the code in a normal view does something like divide 1 by 0 or access the third element in a 2-element array or do anything else that raises a Python exception and the exception is uncaught, I want a special view method to run.  Decorating a function with `@app.errorhandler(500)` does not seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

What you have described is, by default, how Flask works. My assumption is that you are running in debug mode, and therefore exceptions are being shown to you in the debug screen. Make sure debug mode is off, then try again. Here is a [comment directly from the code itself:](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/2ab91446f608755affba035650c1dd74b825a018/flask/app.py#L1446-L1450)

> Default exception handling that kicks in when an exception occurs that
>   is not caught.  In debug mode the exception will be re-raised
>   immediately, otherwise it is logged and the handler for a 500 internal
>   server error is used.  If no such handler exists, a default 500
>   internal server error message is displayed.

Comment: If you try with debug mode off and it's still not working, please post more of your code.

Comment: You are correct, once I disabled debug mode, then then it worked.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I use debug mode so that the code auto-reloads when I make a change during development.  Is there a way to have auto-reloading without debug mode?

Comment: Wait, what?  I just turned on debugging again and the 500 error handler still works AND I get automatic code reloading!  Turning off debug mode again means the 500 handler still works and code doesn't reload (makes sense), but turning debugging back on again keeps the 500 handler working.  That's all good for me, but suspicious.

Comment: When you turn debug on and off, are you actually restarting the process, or just relying on the reload?

Comment: Oh wait, stupid me.  Turns out I actually had `abort(500)` code in there during this time.  When I turn that off I actually get the expected behavior, where I need debug mode off for `app.errorhandler` to work.  Sorry, I feel stupid for wasting your time with that.

Comment: When you say "Default exception handling that kicks in" what exactly is the default exception handling?

Answer (score 29):

It works fine in my side:

```
from flask import Flask ,url_for,render_template,request,abort
from  werkzeug.debug import get_current_traceback
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    try:
        raise Exception("Can't connect to database")
    except Exception,e:
        track= get_current_traceback(skip=1, show_hidden_frames=True,
            ignore_system_exceptions=False)
        track.log()
        abort(500)
    return "index"

@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_error(error):

    return "500 error"

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return "404 error",404

if __name__== "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Flask will not set the error code for you, so make sure to also provide the HTTP status code when returning a response.

Comment: If you use `DEBUG=True` it will not work (print stacktrace), it comfortably on development. So if you want see real 500 pages check that Flask application doesn't run on DEBUG mode.

Comment: I am confused, you want Flask handle the Exception or you want to customer the Exception?

Comment: Handle ofcourse. I mean that when you develop you use debug mode and can be litle bit confused when your 500 error haven't beautiful page instead stacktrace.

Comment: Sure, when you develop, you can just not add `@app.errorhandler(500)`.

Comment: I have updated the code, in most cases, we need catch exception like database can't connect, then we can print the stacktrace, and it also show you customer 500 error page.

Comment: Is there a way to catch 5xx or 4xx family errors instead of setting up handlers for each code individually?

Comment: ```def internal_error(error):

    return "500 error"```  needs to have no blank line between them, python is line and indent sensitive

Comment: @ChuckNorrris It's not as sensitive as you think -- whitespace-only lines are ignored.

Comment: if DEBUG (app.debug) is True put PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS to False so you can keep the auto-reload but turn off the Werkzeug Debugger.

Answer (score 23):

here is my code snippt

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    raise Exception("Can't connect to database")


@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def exception_handler(error):
    return "!!!!"  + repr(error)
```

Comment: `app.debug` didn't work for me, so this saved me! thanks!

Comment: Thanx :) it handled the exception raised by 500 (internal server error)
but another handeling for 404 should be added like:
app.register_error_handler(404, page_not_found)
then :
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('pageNotFound.html'), 404

Answer (score 17):

My solution to this was to turn on the propagation of exceptions, by modifying the config dictionary:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
...
app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True
```

Look at this other related question: [Flask app raises a 500 error with no exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059937/flask-app-raises-a-500-error-with-no-exception)

Comment: Thank you!! I was tearing my hair out and adding this line finally 'threw me a bone' in my log so I could figure it out.  I hate 500 errors!  Why don't they just put 'error: something happened' ;)

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that within the code, not all Exceptions are `HTTPException`, but Flask catches these by default and returns a generic 500 error response (which may or may not include the original error message as described by @Mark Hildreth). Thus, using `@app.errorhandler(500)` will not catch those errors, since this happens before Flask returns the generic 500 error.

You would need to have a generic `errorhandler(Exception)` which works similar to `except Exception:` in python, which captures everything. A good solution is provided in [Flask pallets projects](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/):

```
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException

@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_exception(e):
    # pass through HTTP errors. You wouldn't want to handle these generically.
    if isinstance(e, HTTPException):
        return e

    # now you're handling non-HTTP exceptions only
    return render_template("500_generic.html", e=e), 500
```

You can also return JSON if you'd like and also include the original error message if you're in debug mode. E.g.

```
from flask import jsonify
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException

debug = True  # global variable setting the debug config

@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_exception(e):
    if isinstance(e, HTTPException):
        return e

    res = {'code': 500,
           'errorType': 'Internal Server Error',
           'errorMessage': "Something went really wrong!"}
    if debug:
        res['errorMessage'] = e.message if hasattr(e, 'message') else f'{e}'

    return jsonify(res), 500
```

Answer (score 1):

this code catching 500 status code and get exception error

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def all_exception_handler(e):
    error = str(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: this catches all generic errors is not good practice by itself.