# Flask app raises a 500 error with no exception

Tags: python, exception, heroku, flask

I've been banging my head against this method in Flask for some time, and while it seems I'm making progress now, I've just happened upon something that baffles me to no end. Here is the method I'm calling:

```
@app.route('/facedata/<slug>', methods=["POST"])
def facedata(slug):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get_or_404(slug=slug)
            data = [float(item) for item in request.form.getlist('emotions[]')]
            post.face_data.append(data)
            post.save()
        except:
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
```

For a long time I was getting errors in here that would then be caught in the heroku logs. Currently there are no errors, implying that it doesn't reach the except loop, but even worse, there are still 500 errors. Specifically the 500 errors I get are:

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/facedata/StripedVuitton host=cryptic-mountain-6390.herokuapp.com fwd="18.111.90.180" dyno=web.2 connect=4ms service=39ms status=500 bytes=291
```

I'm sending these `POST` requests via AJAX in this method:

```
var slug = document.getElementById("hidden-slug").getAttribute("value");
data = {emotions: lRes};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    url: document.location.origin + "/facedata/" + slug,
    success: function(){
        console.log("Success!");
    }
});
```

Quite honestly I just don't know how to continue debugging this problem. It doesn't make a lot of sense to me to be getting a traceback without an exception, but maybe I'm just being naive.

I'm using mongoengine on top of MongoHQ on Heroku if that's relevant.

Comment: Try adding "GET" to methods.

Comment: I added it, there was no change. Not sure why there would be...

Comment: Maybe changing `@app.route('/facedata/<slug>'` to `@app.route('/facedata/<slug>/` or `url: document.location.origin + "/facedata/" + slug,` to `url: document.location.origin + "/facedata/" + slug + "/",` would help.

Comment: @solusipse Thanks for the suggestion, but again no change. Except for changing an error to a 404 with mismatched versions

Comment: Do you know that you even GET to the beginning of the `try`?

Comment: @NitzanShaked Yea, I have a number of log statements that return correctly within there. Just didn't post them for sake of brevity.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

After beating my head against this some more I finally figured it out thanks to the awesome people on the pocoo google group (I have since learned that there is a separate list for flask). Firstly, I needed to turn on the `PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS` option in my app configuration (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#builtin-configuration-values).

After that was done I realized there was an issue with not returning a response from a view function, which Flask interpreted this method as. Since that was the case, this issue was resolved by just adding:

```
return jsonify(result={"status": 200})
```

To the end of the `try` block. I hope this helps someone in a similar situation in the future.

Comment: Thanks, this was hard to find. Setting `app.debug = True` takes care of `PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS` and loads of other niceties that help debug flask apps.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same to `return ""`?

Comment: @JeromeJ I'm not sure about the default metadata that `flask` wraps around it's responses, but I think it's better to be explicit here.

Comment: I had this same problem, however in my case, PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS was on, and the exceptions were being swallowed anyway. I was just getting 500 errors with no relevant logs. The problem ended up being caused by `werkzeug.debug.DebuggedApplication`. I was using it in the usual way in __init__.py: `app = DebuggedApplication(app, evalex=True)`. Not sure why it caused the problem, but removing its use allowed exceptions thrown by AJAX POST requests to propagate again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but the underlying cause was different than the one in Slater's response:

I was muting the logger that the stack trace goes to. Be sure that you are not filtering out the `flask.app` logger, which is where the exception stack traces go to (note that this is different than the flask server's informational logs, named `app.api`).