# Elasticsearch very unreliable in returning results with NGINX and UWSGI

Tags: ajax, nginx, elasticsearch, flask, uwsgi

**Summary**: *I have a website with a search-as-you type search through Flask and Elasticsearch. This works perfectly on my local machine, and on my server (a Vultr droplet) when I run flask directly. However, when I run the website through Nginx and uWSGI it suddenly becomes unreliable, returning some results but not others. I have no idea how to troubleshoot this and could use some suggestions or pointers!*

I'll try to provide as much info as possible with regards to my setup:

### Elasticsearch

Server health:

```
   {
      "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
      "status" : "green",
      "timed_out" : false,
      "number_of_nodes" : 1,
      "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
      "active_primary_shards" : 1,
      "active_shards" : 1,
      "relocating_shards" : 0,
      "initializing_shards" : 0,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0,
      "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
      "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
      "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
      "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
      "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
    }
```

Here is pastebin with [info from my index](http://pastebin.com/gTurY1wG)

### Javascript, AJAX and Flask

As the user starts typing, jQuery autocomplete sends out an AJAX request that gets forwarded to elasticsearch (through Flask), where a query is run. The results are returned to javascript and added to the HTML.

I doubt there's a problem here since it works perfectly until I use Nginx, but regardless here is the info:

- [This is the javascript that uses jQuery autocomplete and AJAX with GET](http://pastebin.com/UgFJByrj).
- This calls get_search_results() in the [views.py class](http://pastebin.com/XHfPJ1ye) with an AJAX call
- Lastly get_search_results() gets autocomplete results through the [search_database() function](http://pastebin.com/6Bz51XtC)

### Working correctly

When I run my flask application through my debugging script it works perfectly:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import application
application.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Whenever I start typing autocomplete works promptly and returns the correct results.

### The problem

However, when I run the website as a service through Nginx and uWSGI search results work sometimes, but not others times. Some names are returned, but most are not. Partial strings are almost never returned. I have my server setup in the following way (I basically followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)):

This runs the **flask** application:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

This module gets called by the following **uWSGI** .ini that creates a socket:

```
[uwsgi]
module = run_wsgi

master = true
processes = 5

socket = transfer_website.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

uWSGI gets launched with this .ini by an **upstart script**:

```
description "uWSGI server instance configured to serve Transfer Website"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid admin
setgid www-data

env PATH=/home/admin/transfer_website/transfer-virt-env/bin
chdir /home/admin/transfer_website
exec uwsgi --ini transfer_website.ini
```

Lastly the server accepts requests through **Nginx** that forwards requests to the website socket. This file is in /etc/nginx/sites (I've redacted the IP address of the website):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name /*my.server.ip.address*/;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/admin/transfer_website/transfer_website.sock;
    }
}
```

I've checked the elasticsearch logs and there does not seem to be anything related to this problem at all. My guess is that the problem lies somewhere in the forwarding and AJAX calls but I have no idea how to debug this.

Sorry if this post is vague or if I left our crucial information, I'd be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I finally solved it.

First I isolated the problem by looking at the chrome inspect -> network tab. The results that weren't returned were producing a 500 error.

After some quick googling, I then [found a way](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-check-error-logs-for-flask-uwsgi-nginx-app) to debug and log the uwsgi run flask application (and the 500 error). I added the following line to my uwsgi .ini file:

```
#location of log files
logto = file_name.log
```

This logs all the output from the Flask application to this logfile.

However I still wasn't getting the error, instead the application seemed to ignore it and continue. [This was ultimately fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18063897/4772958) by setting `PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS` to `True` in my config file.

If `Debug = False` the exceptions don't propagate in the interest of not crashing the server. So it has to be explicitly set to force the errors to show up in the log.

Turns out I had some silly error where I tried printing a string that was giving a unidecode error because of encoding problems. Why this wasn't a problem on the local version I'll never know