# How to prevent Flask Server from crashing after flask Exception happened during processing of request from ('x.x.x.x', 12554)

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, web, flask

Flask server usually crashes after the Exception:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('x.x.x.x', 12554)
```

This exception usually comes when some client make certain request and closes its connection before receiving the response. Meanwhile, server tries writing to the pipe for the response, which fails as connection is already closed by the client. And, the web server crashes.

Is there any way we can catch this exception, and stops the web server from crashing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catching a 500 server error in Flask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993318/catching-a-500-server-error-in-flask)

Comment: No its different from the one you mentioned. In that, question one have to catch the response at server and return 500 to the client request.But, in my case client have already closed the connection (similar to the case of timeout) but flask still tries to serve the request by writing response to the closed pipeline. Due to which flask throws the above mentioned exception and crashes.

Comment: How is your Flask application deployed? If Flask is not catching this error and throwing a 500 it means its an error with the WSGI server and not Flask